# Are there deliberate Robot Jox references in Pacific Rim?

Tags: reference, pacific-rim

I stumbled across this gif and was wondering are there any other Easter egg references to *Robot Jox* in *Pacific Rim*? This seems too close to be an accident but cant really find a lot about it out there.

The love interest plot lines have some similarities between the films as well (both fight each other in training for example) but would be interested if there are more obvious deliberate references?

Is there any confirmation from the movies creators?

[image: RobotJoxVsPacificRim]

Comment: I think that's a pretty common gesture for a human about to engage in a fist-fight.  It's not too surprising that it would be used in a movie about giant humanoid robots that engage in fist-fights.  I think your premise that this is "too similar to be an accident" and therefore must be a deliberate reference is flawed.

Comment: Well i do not, and thats enough isn't it

Comment: You're allowed to think whatever you like, of course.  We, the reading public, are also allowed to challenge the frame of the question if we feel it's incorrect.